# How do I remove quotes when I save a list to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I work with the field. Then I work with this field as a list.
I'm trying to put this list back into the array numpy, but I have a problem there that as I insert the letter into the numpy, I get unwanted quotes there.

Could these quotes be removed in any way?
Or modify the code so that I don't have to work to transform the array into a list but continue as an array

I tried using replace to remove them but it doesn't work.
Do you have any other way?

My code

```
import os
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
b = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
z1 = np.array([1, 1])
z2 = np.array([1, 1])
comb_x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
comb_y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
letsgo = [[] for i in range(4)] 
go=np.array([])
for (j), (k) in zip(a, b):
    z1[:] = 0
    z1[:j] = 1
    x12 = z1
    z2[:] = 0
    z2[:k] = 1
    y12 = z2
    for (h),(n),(r) in zip(comb_x,comb_y,np.arange(0,4)):
        #print(h,n,'iteracia = ',r)
        if x12[h] == 1 and y12[n] == 1:
            go=np.append(go,x12,axis=0)

            letsgo[r].append(f'{x12} {y12}')
for list in letsgo:
    for string in list:
        string = ', '.join(string.split())
        #pole=pole.replace("'",'')
        #print(string)
        pole = np.array([string])
        #pole=pole.replace("'",'')
        print(pole)
```

my output:

```
['[1, 0], [1, 0]']
['[1, 0], [1, 1]']
['[1, 1], [1, 0]']
['[1, 1], [1, 1]']
['[1, 0], [1, 1]']
['[1, 1], [1, 1]']
['[1, 1], [1, 0]']
['[1, 1], [1, 1]']
['[1, 1], [1, 1]']
```

required output:

```
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[1, 0], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
[[1, 0], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Basically, I want it to be a standard np.array again.
Can you advise me?

Comment: Why do you turn them into strings if you don't want strings?

Comment: You're converting the list to a string when you do `string = ', '.join(string.split())`

Comment: I couldn't get the required output directly with the array, so I did it through the string

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it. I changed your `letsgo` to be initially just an empty list, and then append `x12` and `y12` (converted to lists to avid the array like output):

```
import os
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
b = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
z1 = np.array([1, 1])
z2 = np.array([1, 1])
comb_x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
comb_y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
#letsgo = [[] for i in range(4)] 
letsgo = []
go=np.array([])
for (j), (k) in zip(a, b):
    z1[:] = 0
    z1[:j] = 1
    x12 = z1
    z2[:] = 0
    z2[:k] = 1
    y12 = z2
    for (h),(n),(r) in zip(comb_x,comb_y,np.arange(0,4)):
        #print(h,n,'iteracia = ',r)
        if x12[h] == 1 and y12[n] == 1:
            go=np.append(go,x12,axis=0)
            letsgo.append([list(x12), list(y12)])

for list in letsgo:
    print(list)
```